# oracledb sequelize ORM

Tags: orm, sequelize

coders.

Necesito realizar una conexión a una base de datos Oracle, por medio de sequelize. El inconveniente es que al seguir los pasos de la documentación no me ha sido posible realizar correctamente la configuración, según se indica debo tener instalado "Visual Studio 2017 Redistributable", busque otra alternativa ingresando el comando: npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools. En los dos casos me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe los pasos que debo seguir, para poder utilizar sequelize con oracledb? En serio, les agradecería su colaboración y buena onda.

Comment: Hola, a todos, ya solucioné el err:

Comment: Hola, a todos, ya solucioné el error. Al intentar realizar una configuración pase el siguiente comando por error: npm config set proxy http://myproxy.example.com:80/, esto hace que npm no busque los paquetes correctamente, para solucionarlo realice lo siguiente:   utilice el comando, npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org" y después npm config set strict-ssl false (anular los valores registryy .strict-ssl). Espero les sirva, un abrazo.